# Is Harry Potter's real name Henry?

Tags: harry-potter, names

Did James and Lily Potter christen Harry "Harry" or "Henry"? I don't recall him ever being referred to as Henry in either the books or the movies, but (in the UK, at least) it would be odd for a boy to actually be named Harry, as it's normally the informal form for Henry. Has JK Rowling said anything about this?

Comment: Lot's of people are called just "Harry". My cousin is just called Harry. It can also be short for Harold.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harry_Styles

Comment: Well, I don't know if she ever made up a birth certificate, but I find it hard to imagine that Ms McGonagall of all people wouldn't have addressed him with his real name at one point if it was Henry, especially during the sorting ceremony

Comment: It is not at all odd for boys to be called Harry in the UK.  It was the third most common given name in 2015: http://www.bbc.com/news/uk-37254187 - admittedly after the book's publication.

Comment: Many "nicknames" have become names in their own right - Fred, Archie, Charlie (all written as is on the birth certificate, rather than Frederick, Archibald or Charles), and similar, have become popular in recent years.

Comment: -1. Bad question because if it is never mentioned, why ever come up with the idea? Or since when is "Hermione" a standard British name?

Comment: I think Harry would be an even more common nickname for Harold.  Also, in the US, a more common nickname for Henry would be Hank.

Comment: The Office For National Statistics data has a graph that shows the popularity of various names in the UK since 1904.https://visual.ons.gov.uk/baby-names-since-1904-how-has-yours-performed/ If you type in Harry there is a clear rise in the popularity of the name the early 1990s. Which is roughly coincidental with Prince Henry being born and popularly being called Harry.

Comment: Yeah sorry, -1. Harry is a normal standadd name, just like Brian or Frederick.

Comment: The real question here is why *didn't* James and Lily name him Henry?

Comment: His name is actually 'Hamy', but due to a misprint, we now know him as 'Harry'

Comment: Hermione has been a British name since _at least_ the 19th century.  And the use of hypocorisms as actual given names is not a novel thing _at all_.  That has been going on for a long time, at least as far back as Anglo-Saxon times.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

## No, his real name is Harry James Potter, not Henry.

There's no evidence that his real name is Henry. Throughout the book he is always called Harry. And his official O.W.L results address him as Harry.

> Harry James Potter has achieved
>
> <sub>*Harry Potter and the Half Blood Prince, Chapter 5*</sub>

As this is an official document, it's almost certain that it would use his legal/official name (as evidenced by the inclusion of his middle name). So his name is just Harry, not Henry.

As pointed out by [ratchet freak](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/8272/ratchet-freak) in the comments, this also happens during his trial in *The Order of the Phoenix*.

> It was a square silver badge with Harry Potter, Disciplinary Hearing
>   on it.
>
> <sub>*Harry Potter and the Order of the Phoenix, Chapter 7*</sub>

> “You are Harry James Potter, of number four, Privet Drive, Little
>   Whinging, Surrey?” Fudge said, glaring at Harry over the top of his
>   parchment.
>
> <sub>*Harry Potter and the Order of the Phoenix, Chapter 8*</sub>

A court of law would undoubtedly use his official name, rather than a nickname (again evidenced by the inclusion of his middle name).

Comment: Same thing happened in his trial at the start of book 5.

Comment: Also, the letters sent to him by Hogwarts in Philosophers Stone.

Comment: @GunnarSödergren I checked those, they're just address to Mr H Potter.

Answer (score 28):

### Dumbledore’s last will clearly states it’s Harry

> “The Last Will and Testament of Albus Percival Wulfric Brian Dumbledore” … yes, here we are … “to **Ronald** Bilius Weasley, I leave my Deluminator, in the hope that he will remember me when he uses it.
> “To **Harry** James Potter,”’ he read, and Harry’s insides contracted with a sudden excitement, ‘“I leave the Snitch he caught in his first Quidditch match at Hogwarts, as a reminder of the rewards of perseverance and skill.”
> <sub>Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows, Chapter 7 (The Will of Albus Dumbledore)</sub>

Note that Dumbledore leaves the Deluminator to *Ronald* Bilius Weasley and the snitch to *Harry* James Potter

Next up we have the hearing with a nice long list of full names, notice Harry is still only called Harry

> “Disciplinary hearing of the twelfth of August,’ said Fudge in a ringing voice, and Percy began taking notes at once, ‘into offences committed under the Decree for the Reasonable Restriction of Underage Sorcery and the International Statute of Secrecy by **Harry** James Potter, resident at number four, Privet Drive, Little Whinging, Surrey.’
> ‘Interrogators: Cornelius Oswald Fudge, Minister for Magic; Amelia Susan Bones, Head of the Department of Magical Law Enforcement; Dolores Jane Umbridge, Senior Undersecretary to the Minister.”
> <sub>Harry Potter and the Order of the Phoenix, Chapter 8 (The Hearing)</sub>

Furthermore, [the Family Tree on Pottermore supports that it's Harry](https://www.pottermore.com/features/the-potter-family-tree)

As you can see from the image below, Harry comes up as Harry.

While Harry's Great-Grandfather, one Henry Potter was:

> Henry Potter (Harry to his intimates)
> <sub>[Potter Family - Pottermore](https://www.pottermore.com/writing-by-jk-rowling/the-potter-family)</sub>

This seems to suggest that he was infact "christened" Harry.

[image: Potter family tree with Harry labelled as Harry and his Great Grandfather, nicknames Harry, as Henry]

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/68519/discussion-between-adamant-and-edlothiad).

Comment: Side note to back up your answer my middle name is "Harry" and is not short for Henry or Harold it is just plain Harry, after my Grandad who was named plain Harry whereas my uncle, his son, is named Henry.

Comment: While I'm sure your conclusion is correct, that family tree doesn't really look like convincing evidence to me, given that it lists Ginny Weasley's first name as Ginny, not Ginevra.

Comment: @IlmariKaronen are my new details more convincing?

Comment: Excellent answer! :) Personally, I think your first two book quotes provide solid proof that his full name is Harry.

Comment: Doesn't look like a tree so much as a family… vine?

Comment: @Kevin don't shoot the messenger

Comment: Note that the family tree wasn't made by Rowling. It was put together by the "Pottermore Team" based off of their own interpretations of Rowling's writings.